# Error: modifier cannot be applied on multi-user data

Tags: modifiers, linked-data

I couldn't apply a Boolean Modifier to duplicate linked object and object array. I got this message in both case:

> modifier cannot be applied on multi-user data

Why couldn't I apply the Boolean Modifier, and what do I have to do so that I can apply modifiers in scenarios like this?

Comment: Thanks, the first part is working for me, however I wanted to preserve the shape keys - to import them to . So I am trying to do as follows: - Make a duplicate of the entire collection - On the copy: - Remove shape keys and un-parant - **Apply** the modifier - Then re-link (this is perhaps where things go wrong?) - Mirror the shape keys from the Original to the The shape keys are visible but they are not working... I think the are getting mirrored, but not to all of my meshes..?? The mesh I am working with is a Makehuman character where I try to create shape-keys for expressions etc. This work

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you have a linked object from another scene, you won't be able to apply any modifiers to it. You will have to unlink it by clicking the unlink button in the object properties panel and possibly also in the data properties panel.

[image: unlink object]

If you have two objects, which reference to the same data, you will have to make them a single user.
This is done by either clicking the users icon in the data context. This will make the data single user. Both objects will now be individual copies.

[image: make single user]

You can also press <kbd>U</kbd> in the 3D viewport, then select **Object & Data**.
[image: make single user with shortcut]

#### Method of linking the objects back together

- With the unedited object selected, set the mesh *datablock* in the *Object Data* section of the *Properties Panel* to the edit mesh.
- Select the unedited objects, then select the edited object. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and select *Object Data* to link the objects to the same datablock.

[image: linking objects]

#### Apply Modifier to Multi User Python Script

I have added a script to do exactly what the question describes: *Apply All Modifiers to Multi-User Datablock.*

Just paste this in the text editor, when you want to apply all modifiers to a mesh, hit the run script button of the text editor.

You can resize the text editor until only the RUN SCRIPT button is visible to save space. If you want to add this functionality to Blender, check out [how to add a python addon](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_65_5/info_tutorial_addon.html).

```
import bpy

def applyModifierToMultiUser(scene):
    active = scene.objects.active
    if (active == None):
        print("Select an object")
        return
    if (active.type != "MESH"):
        print("Select an mesh object")
        return
    mesh = active.to_mesh(scene, True, 'PREVIEW')
    linked = []
    selected = []
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        if obj.data == active.data:
                linked.append(obj)
    for obj in bpy.context.selected_editable_objects:
        selected.append(obj)
        obj.select = False

    for obj in linked:
        obj.select = True
        obj.modifiers.clear()
    active.data = mesh
    bpy.ops.object.make_links_data(type='OBDATA')

    for obj in linked:
        obj.select = False
    for obj in selected:
        obj.select = True
scn = bpy.context.scene
applyModifierToMultiUser(scn)
```

Comment: So you are saying that I can't develop all parts in the same time? because the result to what you suggest is unlink the objects, and any farther update will not auto applied on the others (the purpose of linking in the first place)

Comment: Yes, as far as I know this is a limitation that has no better solution. I have added an explanation on linking objects back together to the answer.

Comment: So I unlink, apply modifier then relink, I didn't though relinking will apply the update,Thanks for that.

Comment: I have extended the answer with a python script, which does exactly, what you asked for.

Comment: What's the equivalent Python code to 'clicking the users icon in the data context'?

Comment: This is a gist with a function for 2.93 performing the same on a modified Unity editor Blender to FBX script
https://gist.github.com/Baccanno/385f65d1a5cde0ad9809588458fff99e

If using unity just replace the script in your editor folder. (unity LTS 2019.4.40)

Answer (score 17):

In Blender 2.8 here is where you can find "make single user":

[image: make single user]

Note that there is also "make single user" when you right click on the object in the scene collection, but as of this writing you just get "not implemented" if you try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Blender 2.9.1 and it's not implemented, but a work around was to export an FBX and import it into the same scene, apply material and you're good to go.